# Convert SQL query with an "In" condition to Lambda expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

This may be quite simple, but unfortunately I have a difficulty in figuring out converting an SQL query with an "In" condition to lambda.

```
SELECT * 
FROM cm_wfapp 
WHERE recgid IN (select distinct wfapp_id from cm_wftrn where approver_id = 32060)
```

Is there any way to convert this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untested (for obvious reasona), but you could try:

```
var query = from app in db.wfapp
            where db.wftrn.Where(x => x.approver_id==32060)
                          .Select(x => x.wfapp_id).Contains(app.recgid)
            select app
```

Let me know whether it works, though.

Alternatively: consider writing it *as SQL*; most ORms offer a pass-thru mechanism.

Comment: Marc, would that search for `x.approver_id == 32060` in `wftrn` in each iteration ?

Comment: @Habib that depends on what the provider is; the OP suggests (by mentioning sql) that it is something like EF/L2S, in which case I would *expect* that to go down as a single composed TSQL query; and explicitly *not* to search for the approver_id for each `app` iteration

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `.Select(x => x.wfapp_id)` after your where-clause?

Comment: @Dirk darn, yes; disadvantage of not being able to test it

Comment: To EveryOne: thank so much for the helpful comments, highly appreciate it.. by getting ideas base from the answers that you guys gave,respectively. did run a several trial and error test and i came out to this: 

app = app.Where(w => db.lxm_wftrns.Any(s => s.appr_id ==  int.Parse("32060")));

again thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

For clearness you can do 2 queries in `LINQ`. Remeber that `LINQ` has defered execution model, so *actual* query will be generated in the moment of actual request.

So you can try to do something like this:

```
var ids = wfapp_id.Where(i=>i.approver_id == 32060); 

//after use a ids in yor final query. 
var result = cm_wfapp.Where(id=>ids.Contains(id.recgid));
```

This *should* produce optimal result, but you need to test it agains real DB and its data, to see if `LINQ` generates good `SQL` or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a `List<int>` for your sub query like:

```
List<int> listOfWfaap_id = dbContext.cm_wftrn
                                .Where(r=> r.approver_id == 32060)
                                .ToList();
```

Then use `Contains` to check for each ID like:

```
var result = dbContext.cm_wfapp
                    .Where(r=> listOfWfapp_id.Contains(r=> r.recgid);
```

You may see: [Creating IN Queries With Linq To Sql](http://wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql)

Comment: Calling `ToList` on the  early query may be a bad idea if it prevents composition - there could be vast numbers of rows forced over the wire by the first query. It obviously depends on the context, though

Answer (score 1):

If you are using entity framework pre version 6 and `.Contains()` it is not natively supported:

[Native support for Enumerable.Contains](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/245)

Answer (score 0):

You could build your own extension-method like this:

http://geekswithblogs.net/EltonStoneman/archive/2010/07/11/where-in-style-queries-in-linq-to-entities.aspx

which you can use like this:

```
var result = cm_wfapp.WhereIn(wfapp_id.Where(i=>i.approver_id == 32060));
```